# In C#, how do I make the left hand side border of the datagridview disappear?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, border, borderless

I wanna make the left hand border of the datagridview object disappear. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of what you actually mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case it is WinForms the property is called `RowHeadersVisible`. Set that to false and you won't see the left hand side border.

Answer (score 4):

If you 're talking about the row headers, in the properties pane set `RowHeadersVisible` to `False`.

Comment: There is grey index like column on the left hand side of the datagrid, I tried what you said, but that grey portion didn't disappear.

Comment: Do you have the `AutoSizeRows` property set to `AllHeaders`?

Comment: I'm a newbie and I don't have the privelege to upload pics yet. But here's a picture I found on Google Images, the grey column that also has an asterix to indicate that that's the selected row. Is it possible to make that disappear? http://bit.ly/sKB4ls

Comment: Have you tried saving your form, and reloading it, just in case it's a Visual Studio glitch?

Comment: @IoannisKaradimas: Thanks, it worked when I reopened and built it again.